# Rank and determinant of $D$ , an $n\times n$ real matrix, $n\ge 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $D$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix, $n\ge 2$. Which of the following is valid?

1. $\det(D)=0\Rightarrow \mathrm{rank}(D)=0$
2. $\det(D)=1\Rightarrow \mathrm{rank}(D)\neq 1$
3. $\det(D)=1\Rightarrow \mathrm{rank}(D)\neq0$
4. $\det(D)=n\Rightarrow \mathrm{rank}(D)\neq 1$

Well, (1) is wrong because there is a $3\times 3$ matrix with rank $2$ and determinant $0$, namely $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

I am confused about the other three: please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

1. The following are equivalent

   - A square matrix is invertible
   - A square matrix has full rank
   - A square matrix has non-zero determinant
2. The rank of the matrix is between $0$ and $n$
3. More than one may be correct

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to #1 is fine!

For #2, #3 and #4, we should make sure you are aware there is a simple fact: a matrix $A$ over a field is invertible iff it has nonzero determinant iff it has full rank (rank $n>1$ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What do you know about the relation between invertibility (non-singularity) of a given matrix and its determinant? What can you say about the rank of an invertible (or non-singular) matrix?

Comment: If it has non zero determinant and full rank.

Comment: so $3$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @Mex: Yes, if it has non-zero determinant, then it has full rank (a fact that has been mentioned twice in the other answers). And yes, #3 is correct, but it is not the only one...

Comment: also $4$ may be correct.

Comment: @Mex: How about #2? (And #4 *may* be correct?)

Comment: yes that is also true...