# Is there a way of getting these vectors linearly independent?

Tags: matrices, number-systems

I'm hoping that we can find a way to get the following matrix to have full rank:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        (x^a)_1 & (x^{2a})_1 & (x^{3a})_1 & \dots & (x^{na})_1\\
        (x^a)_2 & (x^{2a})_2 & (x^{3a})_2 & \dots & (x^{na})_2\\
        (x^a)_3 & (x^{2a})_3 & (x^{3a})_3 & \dots & (x^{na})_3\\
        \dots   & \dots    & \dots    & \dots & \dots   \\
        (x^a)_m & (x^{2a})_m & (x^{3a})_m & \dots & (x^{na})_m\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here $x$ has multiplicative order $na, n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{N}$.  The subscripts $1,2,3,\dots, m$ denote the $m$th component in an $m$ component number system.  For example, if we're working with quaternions, then $m=4$, and $x_1$ is the real component, $x_2$ the $i$ component, $x_3$ the $j$ component, and $x_4$ the $k$ component.

**Can we find an $x$ with multiplicative order $na$ that will give the matrix full rank?**

Comment: If it helps, we can use modular arithmetic, with all components modulo one natural number.

Answer (score 1):

**A few initial observations:**

1. Using modular arithmetic can only hurt us, because it makes more numbers equal to other numbers, so that it becomes more likely that a row is a linear combination of other rows.
2. If by "$m$ component number system" you mean something where the components are real numbers, multiplication is associative, and division is possible, then [the *only* number systems like that are the reals, the complexes, and the quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29).
3. Once we have an example for the $n=m$ case, then if it weren't for the order condition, we could keep the same $x$ and just throw in more columns for $n>m$ because the row rank can't go down, and it's already full with only $m$ rows.
4. [In the complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) and [in the quaternions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420697/is-the-set-of-quaternions-mathbbh-algebraically-closed) you can take the $a^\text{th}$ root of numbers without any problems, so if it weren't for the "order $na$" condition, the $x^a$ could be replaced by $x$ in those cases without losing any generality.

---

**The real numbers ($m=1$):**

If it weren't for the order condition, then any nonzero $x$ works for any $n,a$, and $x=0$ works for no $n,a\ge1$.

To take the order condition into account, note that the only real numbers with finite order are $\pm1$, so the only allowed cases are $x=-1,a=2,n=1$, $x=-1,a=1,n=2$, and $x=1,a=1,n=1$. $\left[(-1)^2\right]=[1]$, $\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $[1]$ all have full rank.

---

**The complex numbers ($m=2$):**

First, let's ignore the order condition and figure out what solutions we can get with $a=1,n=2$. Since the matrix is square, [we can simply use the determinant to test for full rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/156941/26369). If $x=A+Bi$, then $x^2=A^2-B^2+2ABi$, so that the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}A&A^2-B^2\\B&2AB\end{bmatrix}$. The determinant is $B(A^2+B^2)$ which is nonzero exactly when $B\ne0$. Note that there is no hope of a $B=0$ case having full rank even because of a later column ($n>2$), because if $B=0$ then the second row contains all zeros.

Now, when we impose the order condition, we need the order to be $na$ and we need $x^a$ not to be real. The only finite order real numbers are $\pm1$ and $n\ge2$ so the only problem to worry about is $x^a=-1$, $n=2$. But conversely, order $2a\,$ *forces* $x^a=-1$ since $x^a$ is a square root of $1$ and the order isn't $a$. Therefore, just pick $n>2$ and any $a$ and let $x$ be a primitive $\left(na\right)^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, and it'll work (and nothing else will).

---

**The quaternions ($m=4$):**

Again, let's ignore the order condition and assume $a=1,n=4$ this time. Letting $x=R+Ai+Bj+Ck$, our matrix becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}R&R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2&R\left(R^2-3A^2-3B^2-3C^2\right)&\star\\A&2AR&A(3R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)&4AR(R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)\\B&2BR&B(3R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)&4BR(R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)\\C&2CR&C(3R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)&4CR(R^2-A^2-B^2-C^2)\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $\star=R^4+A^4+B^4+C^4-6R^2(A^2+B^2+C^2)+2\left(A^2B^2+A^2C^2+B^2C^2\right)$. The problem with this is that rows 2,3, and 4 are all multiples of each other (or worse: zero), so this $4\times4$ matrix can have rank at most 2. Like in the complex case, the rank equals 2 as long as $x$ isn't real.

There is also no hope of a higher rank matrix by taking $n>4$ (you can prove this with [the polar form of a quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions#Exponential.2C_logarithm.2C_and_power), for instance). This is all related to the fact that [the commutative subrings of the quaternions are copies of $\mathbb C$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions#Commutative_subrings).

We don't even have to think about the order condition because there's no way to get full rank, period.